# Testing methods that get and set attributes in Rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

This is the only code example from the [rspec website](http://rspec.info/):

```
# bowling_spec.rb
require 'bowling'

describe Bowling, "#score" do
  it "returns 0 for all gutter game" do
    bowling = Bowling.new
    20.times { bowling.hit(0) }
    bowling.score.should eq(0)
  end
end
```

If a requirement of a project was to have a test for every method, what would a test for `#hit` look like?

I can see that this test (once multiple examples are added) would test both `#hit` and `#score` but is there a better way to isolate each? Or is the right approach just to say that the one test is testing both methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a requirement of a project was to have a test for every method

So you have a bureaucratic problem, not a technical one. If one method is simple enough (`hit`) to be entirely specified as a side effect specifying another method (`score`), then it's redundant to redo the spec just to focus on the setter. But if you must do it you can just copy it and adjust the existing descriptions, e.g.:

```
describe Bowling, "#hit" do
  it "sets score to 0 for all gutter game" do
    bowling = Bowling.new
    20.times { bowling.hit(0) }
    bowling.score.should eq(0)
  end
end
```

... which seems like cruft to me.